# Node FS not finding folder

Tags: node.js, fs

Using Node, I create a folder and then have a file in that folder.  I created a function to delete it, but it absolutely refuses to find the folder.

Here's my function:

```
function deleteFile(path) {
  if( !fs.existsSync(path) ) {
    setTimeout(deleteFile(path), 500)
  } else {
    fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file){
      var curPath = path + "/" + file;
      if(fs.lstatSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { // recurse
        deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
      } else { // delete file
        fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
      }
    });
    fs.rmdirSync(path);
  }
}
```

It will continue to recurse until it hits maximum call stack and crash, but the folder exists LONG before that happens.  As you can see, there exists both the folder and the file inside of it.  Could someone please help me fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this issue, I figured it out.  When the folder is created, it gives the incorrect permissions.  I used `fs.chmod` to change permissions beforehand, and that fixed it.